# npm scripts: need to minify all HTML files in folder (and subfolders)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I want to minify all `.html` files in a folder (and any folders within) using `npm run` script. Ideally, all `.html` files should be overwritten (if that's not possible, a new folder is acceptable). It is assumed that there will be non-HTML files in the input folder.

npm library `minimize` works only on per-file but not on folders.

Another npm library `html-minifier` does accept folder as input, but fails if there are any non-HTML files present in the input folder:

```
html-minifier --input-dir ./test1 --output-dir ./test2 --html-5 --collapse-whitespace
```

I need this to minify my static website's HTML files.

Comment: Grunt and gulp are a couple tools that bundle this (and a lot of other stuff) into plugins.  You can define what plugins run and then either run natively or call them from an npm run script.

Comment: That's indeed an option to add Grunt/Gulp as an intermediary for `npm run` to run, but I'd rather avoid that — npm scripts is meant to be a substitute for Grunt/Gulp. I'm seeking pure `npm script` option.

Comment: Does 'minimize' not work with globs?

Answer (score 16):

Since posting original question here on SO, `html-minifier` added the feature to ignore the non-HTML files. Now you can set directories and `html-minifier` won't error-out when it encounters non-HTML files.

Usage example, taken from my working npm task:

```
html-minifier --input-dir ./public --output-dir ./public --collapse-whitespace --file-ext html
```

Let's minify all our static websites' HTML files now!